# Setting the System proxy using _JAVA_OPTIONS/net.properties

Tags: windows-10, proxy, java

My java application  connect/listen  to a server(which is present on another geographic location).

To connect to that server I need to set the proxy.

One way I set the proxy is using environment variable _JAVA_OPTION :

_JAVA_OPTION=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=abc.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=111 -Dhttps.proxyHost=def.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=112 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|10...|.foo.com|etc

Using above way I can connect/listen to server.

Now, I do not want to use the above approach. As an alternative approach, Can I set the proxy using net.properties file available at the path java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1\jre\lib.

I have tried to set the proxy in net.properties file as shown below:
java.net.useSystemProxies=true

http.proxyHost=abc.com
http.proxyPort=111
http.nonProxyHosts= localhost|127.0.0.1|10...|.foo.com|etc

https.proxyHost=abc.com
https.proxyPort=112

but this didn’t work.

Can  I use this alternative approach to set the proxy?

If not then, what are the alternative options available to me to set the proxy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific.